# How to use s:convertEntity with h:selectManyCheckbox and s:selectItems?

Tags: jsf-2, seam

I'm having a problem with `<s:convertEntity>` in `<h:selectManyCheckbox>`. I'm getting this error:

> Unkown Entity com.example.EntityName

But with my entity I can persist and retrieve values from it. Here is the code:

```
<h:selectManyCheckbox value="#{bean.selectedUser}">
    <s:selectItems value="#{bean.usersList}" var="_user" itemValue="#{_user}" label="#{_user.userName}" />
    <s:convertEntity />
</h:selectManyCheckbox>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Using itemValue passes that object directly to the converter, you are passing the entire list to it:

```
value="#{bean.usersList}" var="_user" itemValue="#{_user}"
```

If you use instead:

```
var="_user" value="#{bean.usersList}"
```

will pass the value of each item to the converter.

Edited to fix glaring error and add:

So your final component would be:

```
<h:selectManyCheckbox value="#{bean.selectedUser}">
    <s:selectItems var="_user" value="#{bean.usersList}" label="#{_user.userName}" />
    <s:convertEntity />
</h:selectManyCheckbox>
```

I'm assuming that bean.selectedUser will be a list of users

Comment: is it OK that there is two value attribute there? one for value of the list instance and one for passing each from the items?

Comment: i see. i will try this one out. But may i ask what's the difference of itemValue and value property I'm a little confuse about the usage of the two since you remove it from my example. Many thanks. :)

Comment: i still get the same error. unknown entity. What am i missing here? Can you give me links for example using s:convertEntity. :(

Comment: Do you have an equals method for your entity? What happens if you remove the convertEntity tag?  Can you post the stacktrace?  What does your components.xml file look like?     Take a look at the  [Seam documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.2.2.Final/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e28716)

Answer (score 0):

value of h:selectManyCheckbox  must reference to a array or collection
likw

```
<h:selectManyCheckbox value="#{bean.selectedUserList}">
<s:selectItems value="#{bean.usersList}" var="_user" itemValue="#{_user}" label="#{_user.userName}" />
<s:convertEntity />
```

Comment: yes the value in my checkbox references to list of selectedUser. but i want to know the usage of s:convertEntity